# How do I exclude BootstrapVue from purgeCSS in the production build? (Using Nuxt.js)

Tags: javascript, sass, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js, pagespeed

While trying to further optimize my webapplicaitons pagespeed I have been trying to get the purgeCSS Module to work properly with Nuxt.js - and gotten it to work in the dev environment.

purgeCSS has problems with identifying which portion of the bootstrap/-vue css is actually being used, which is why I decided to just import the parts of bootstrap I need myself and let purgeCSS ignore it. This ended up looking like this:

```
/* css/custom.scss */
/* purgecss start ignore */
$font-family-sans-serif:      "Fauna One", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji" !default;
$font-family-monospace:       "Fauna One", SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace !default;

$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #E40C2B,
  "secondary": #1d1d2c,
  "success": #438945
); 

@import 'bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss';

@import 'bootstrap/scss/_buttons.scss';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/_card.scss';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/_carousel.scss';
/* The list goes on */

@import 'bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
/* purgecss end ignore */
```

Notice the `/* purgecss start/end ignore/*`-comments.

Additionally, I have set up the purgeCSS config in my nuxt.config.js file like this:

```
// nuxt.config.js
  purgeCSS: {
    paths: [
      'components/*.vue',
      'layouts/*.vue',
      'pages/*.vue',
      'plugins/*.js',
      'css/*.scss',
      'css/*.css'
    ],
    styleExtensions: ['.scss'],
    fontFace: true,
    kayframes: true,
    variables: true,
    whitelist: ['mq-editable-field', 'mq-math-mode', 'mqInput'],
    whitelistPatterns: [/mq*/]
  }
```

This worked like a charm in the local dev environment, however breaks the site by excluding **all bootstrap styles** in the final build (production).

My guess is that it has something to do with the `css/custom.scss` file being named differently in the final build and therefore somehow being excluded.

Would be very glad if somebody might have an idea how to make this work in production as well.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/Developmint/nuxt-purgecss/issues/49) which seems to have the same issue as you (though a different framework than bootstrap), and they used [this plugin](https://github.com/qodesmith/purgecss-whitelister) to solve it. Might be worth a try?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply! Just tried it and it does not seem to fix the problem. It also adds quite a bit of bundle weight for its purpose https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=purgecss-whitelister@2.4.0

Comment: Its bundle size shouldn't really matter since it's a compile tool, so it's not something the client downloads. Unless I'm misunderstanding. However, if it didn't fix the issue i guess it doesn't matter. Thought it was worth suggesting though.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation on the `styleExtensions` option you're using, what does it do? Have you tried changing it to `css`?

Comment: It is set to `css` by default. See: https://purgecss.com/guides/nuxt.html#nuxt-js-plugin
However I also did not find any documentation as to what it does. Changing it back to default `css` changes absolutely nothing in dev mode. :´)
Furthermore I have removed all of the `css/*` paths and it did not change anything in dev mode either. I am really confused.

Comment: It clearly does purge in dev mode though, as the styles of the nuxt build loading icon are completely gone for example.